# Angular JS Error - $injector:modulerr

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm, bower

I am trying to view an angular app on a local server using npm, bower and grunt. I am using the exact code (from a cloned repository) that my colleague is using. He is able to view the full app correctly on a local server whereas I get the following error:

Failed to instantiate module [appName] due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417...

He is using a PC and I am on Mac. Does anyone have any suggestions for why he can see the app properly and I cannot?

Thanks

Comment: Will you please share your code in your question as well ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an issue with your server setup.

He likely has a port setup on his server (`http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417...`) - where :9000 is the port.

I'm going to guess that you do not have the same port setup in your bindings. So your version isn't loading the `angular.min.js` where his is.

You could try removing the `:9000` part of the url. This will then make the site look at your `localhost` for the js file.

**This is assuming** that you're even running a server on your machine? you mention a mac, so guessing perhaps not.

In that case, use the CDN https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js

So change:

`http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js`

To

`https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js`

Comment: Thanks Darren, I will try this. Much appreciated!